# How do I force WordPress thumbnails to stretch to fit if uploaded image if it has smaller dimensions?

Tags: php, wordpress

Users on my site upload images that are less than my WordPress theme's essential thumbnail dimensions. How can I force these types of images to stretch vertically or horizontally so there is no blank space?

My `wp-admin>settings>media>thumbnail size` is set to `124px x 156px`. Uploaded images that are `60px x 190px` destroy the website layout. www.sharehouse.co is the test site.
This code below is what needs to be altered.

```
<div class="post-left">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" <?php if ((get_option('cp_ad_image_preview') == 'yes') && (cp_get_image_url_raw($post->ID, 'large', 1) == true)) { ?>class="preview" rel="<?php echo cp_get_image_url_raw($post->ID, 'large', 1); ?>" <?php } ?>><?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'images', true)) cp_single_image_legacy($post->ID, get_option('thumbnail_size_w'), get_option('thumbnail_size_h'), 'preview'); else cp_get_image_url_feat($post->ID, 'thumbnail', 'preview', 1); ?></a>                
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the first thing you need to do is strip the hardcoded width and height attributes from the `img` HTML that WordPress creates. It figures you should have those dimensions and forces you to use them.

Taken from: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/filter-to-remove-image-dimension-attributes

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );

function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html ) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```

Then it's just CSS

```
.attachment img {
  width: 100%; /* scale to width of container, or whatever you want */
}
```

Comment: Wow. Fast response! So do I add your above code to the code in my question? Where do I add it? I found that code using firebug - I'm not a coder.

Comment: The first bit would *probably* go in your `functions.php` file, though it may depend on how your site is set up. Most likely it goes there. The CSS goes in your `style.css` file. The CSS provided will make all images fit their containers, though, so make sure to change it to work how you want.